# Using ModelBuilder Project Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

I have a model I've created that takes an input .CSV file with coordinates/projection that re-projects the input coordinates into several other coordinate systems.

My issue is the model will only run up to the first "project" process and every process after that becomes invalidated (becomes white and won't run). Once I reconnect the feature layer to the first "project" process it works and runs the rest of the model. Once I save and close the model or validate the model I'm back to step 1 and the model only works to the first "project" process.

Here's the model after I've got it all working:

[image]

This is the model after I validate it or reopen it:

[image]

After I reconnect the variable below it works again:

[image]

I don't want to have to do this every time I run this model.

How do I get the "Project" tool to not break, and stay validated?

I even made variables for input coordinate system, output coordinate system, and geographic transformation, but it still breaks.

Comment: what is your check input co-ordinate script doing and what are its outputs that are the preconditions to your copy tools?

Comment: It's checking the input coordinate system of the CSV coordinates. The outputs are 1 of 3 coordinates systems so it knows which leg of the model to proceed down.

Comment: And what are the two calculate value tools inputting into the project tool, edit your question add an explanation and image of the project tool please?